# Should a server be able to execute a second request whilst a current request is sleeping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC and IIS version 7.5.

I have the following action in a controller.

```
public ActionResult Wait(int time = 10000)
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;

    Thread.Sleep(time);

    var end = DateTime.Now;

    var diff = (end - start);

    return Json(new {
        start = start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"),
        end = end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"),
        milliseconds = diff.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,###"),
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If I visit:
/wait?time=10000

Then:
/wait?time=10

The second request will not even being to execute until the first has finished.

Is this normal behaviour, or should each request be executed in its own thread?

To put this in context, in our application, different calls might need to ask data from different servers, and I don't want to have to wait for one complex request to finish before several simpler ones (requiring only local data) can execute.

**edit**

I just realised I am talking about requests from the same user (in the same session).  I think I am just being dim, but maybe someone can still help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

> Concurrent Requests and Session State
>
> Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means
>   that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each
>   separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent
>   requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID
>   value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session
>   information. The second request executes only after the first request
>   is finished. (The second session can also get access if the exclusive
>   lock on the information is freed because the first request exceeds the
>   lock time-out.) If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page
>   directive is set to ReadOnly, a request for the read-only session
>   information does not result in an exclusive lock on the session data.
>   However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait
>   for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.

Comment: Thank you.  So I add this attribute to the controller and I am done (?):  [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]

Comment: Probably, or it might be possible to make the controller action asynchronous so you are not blocking like that. I am guessing that the Thread.Sleep was in there as an example and you're not actually doing something that silly.